# Веб камера, qr код и javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, qrcode

Всем добрый день!

Встала задача, элементарная по своему существу но сложная в реализации.

После заполнения формы на сайте, требуется включить веб камеру, считать **qr** код с бейджика и с него внести считанные данные к примеру Ф.И.О. в скрытое поле и после этого сделать доступным `submit`. Может быть кто то сталкивался  подобными задачами?

В интернете не смог найти хотя бы примерно похожую задачу или готовый фреймворк

Comment: как вариант: https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode